# Conversion from std::wstring to ISO Latin1 format in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a need to convert from std::wstring to ISO Latin1. After reading several forums, I landed in a confusion. wstring is supports unicode character set in which each is two bytes where as ISO Latin1 is just 1 byte. But first 256 code points are same for both.

1. Is ISO Latin-1 is a multi byte string? If so do I need to use wstombs() to convert from wstring to ISO Latin-1

2.Do I have a need to convert the input wstring to ISO LATIN-1, if so how to achieve that? 
Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Are you sure you want ISO Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1)?  The most common encoding on Windows is CP-1252, which is very similar, but not quite the same thing.  "It is very common to mislabel Windows-1252 text with the charset label ISO-8859-1." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: Also note that `std::wstring` can hold a LOT of characters that cannot be converted to ISO Latin 1 or Windows CP-1252.

Comment: Yes, I want my wstring to be converted to ISO Latin-1. User gives me wstring and my api takes only ISO latin characters. I know that ISO latin-1 is just 8 bits but wchar_t is 16 bits. Do I need to truncate explicitly. How do I achieve that? Any example would help....

Comment: Also, the question makes no sense "I have a need to convert from std::wstring to ISO Latin1."  "Do I have a need to convert the input wstring to ISO LATIN-1?"  Those don't match well.

Comment: Here I am asking, is der any explicit need or direct assignment works. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**In Windows** `wchar_t` is 16 bits.

When there are no surrogate pairs (character represented as 2 successive `wchar_t` values) you know that any `wchar_t` value <256 is Latin-1, and otherwise not.

Surrogate pair values are easily recognizable as such because they are in a value range reserved for such.

Actually, this means that you know that any `wchar_t` value <256 is Latin-1, and otherwise not, regardless of surrogate pairs.

And no, Latin-1 is not a multibyte encoding. "Multibyte" refers to encodings where the number of bytes per character can vary.

Comment: @user3794634: re the declaration `std::wstring = L"ABCdefgh$%^&*"; `, it's valid but what's the point -- why are you posting that?

Comment: std::wstring x =L"ABCdef!@#$";
wchar_t* wcharptr= x.c_str();
char* buff = new char[11];

Fun(wchar*t arg) //which actaully should convert this wchar to ISO Latin1 array
{
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 buff[i] =arg[i]; //is this buff now contains ISO Latin 1 string or not
}
}

Comment: My need is to convert a wstring to char* buffer. As wstring characters are 16 bits and char is 8 bits and if char value is <256, direct assignment will workor not. if copied, char* buffer is now considered to be ISO Latin1 or not.